# Upgrading Javascript from UIWebView to WKWebView (using SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, uiwebview, wkwebview

I have just upgraded all the codes of my old application based on UIWebView to WKWebView.
But I'm actually stuck on a javascript function:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)
{
    webView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true;
    let GetTokensFunction = "var BYB_GetFcmTokens = function(udid,token){ alert(udid);alert(token); };"
    
    webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: callGetToken);
}
```

In particular I need to print the Firebase Token on an alert, and then with another javascript send it to my MySQL database to send user notification to a certain user.
How do you suggest implementing this code on the new WKWebView based on SwiftUI ?

***Home.swift***

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct Home: UIViewRepresentable{
    
    let url: URL?
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let prefs = WKWebpagePreferences()
        prefs.allowsContentJavaScript = true
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.defaultWebpagePreferences = prefs
        return WKWebView (
            frame: .zero,
            configuration: config)
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        guard let homeURL = url else {
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: homeURL)
        uiView.load(request)
    }

}
```

***ContentView.swift***

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View{
    var body: some View{
        
        TabView{

            Home(url: URL(string:"home-url"))
                .tabItem{
                    Image(systemName: "house")
                    Text("Home")
                }
            Search(url: URL(string:"search-url"))
                .tabItem{
                    Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                    Text("Search")
                }
            Notification(url: URL(string:"notificationpage-url"))
                .tabItem{
                    Image(systemName: "bell")
                    Text("Notification")
                }
            Menu(url: URL(string:"menu-url"))
                .tabItem{
                    Image(systemName: "gear")
                    Text("Menu")
                }
        }
        .accentColor(Color("tint"))
        
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Please ask me if you need other information!
Hoping to find someone that could help me, have a nice coding day ;)

Comment: Is your question just where to put your `webViewDidFinishLoad` or is it how to implement the functionality you describe in your second paragraph?

Comment: Hi jnpdx, I need to implement the function
```let GetTokensFunction = "var BYB_GetFcmTokens = function(udid,token){ alert(udid);alert(token); };"```

after ```webViewDidFinishLoad```